# Enzyme renders wrapped component rather than base component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, enzyme-to-snapshot

I am snapshot testing my React app with Jest and Enzyme. I am trying to export a testable version of my component that is not wrapped in a higher order component.

I then want to export the wrapped component so my app can use it, and also a testable version, i.e. a non wrapped version of my component.

This is my component:

**NavBar.jsx**

```
const NavBar = ({props}) => {(
  <div>...</div>
)}

export { NavBar as TestableNavBar };

export default withStyles(styles)(NavBar);
```

**NavBar.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { TestableNavBar } from './NavBar';

const props = {
  ...
};

describe('Navbar', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestableNavBar {...props} />);
    const tree = toJson(wrapper);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The above produces a snapshot that looks like this:

```
<div>
  <withStyles(AppBar)
    className=""
  >
    <withStyles(Toolbar)
      disableGutters={true}
    >
      <withStyles(IconButton)
        aria-label="open drawer"
        className=""
        color="contrast"
        onClick={[Function]}
      >
      ...
</div>
```

I can't really make sense of why it still tries to render the HOC?

Comment: Are you sure is it really rendering the HOC? The first rendered element is a `div` as declared in `NavBar` return value.

Comment: @toomuchdesign true. But then you have all the`<withStyles(AppBar) className="">` which seems a bit confusing to me. Why are they there? And as an aside, the output from this test is the same as when I render the default exported NavBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enzyme's `shallow`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#shallow-rendering) method just renders the children declared in render method (`AppBar`, `Toolbar`, and so on), and the output shows that they are wrapped by the same `withStyles` HOC.

Exporting the testable version of your root component allows you to actually test its real output (`div`), but won't prevent its children component from being wrapped by `withStyles` HOC.

If you want to test the final output of your component you might consider switching to [Enzyme's `mount`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#full-dom-rendering) rendering method.

Comment: Ok. Thanks toomuchdesign. Is there another way you would recommend testing this, or will I just have to live with it

Comment: I'd personally go for shallow testing the parent component and -with separate tests- the children. If you want to test the tree as a whole you can use Enzyme's mount, which performs a full DOM rendering of your tree. (See update answer)